# Data will not pass back to previous tableview controller

Tags: swift, uitableview, xcode7.3

Trying to pass the label on selected cell on TableViewController Two back to a label on a static cell on TableViewController one when i hit the back button. Im getting the correct label at the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath()`. but the data will not pass back when i try to print it. I've tried numerous scenarios and came here as a last resort. any help would be appreciated thank you!

tableviewcontroller one:

```
class SearchTableViewController: UITableViewController, SortProtocol {

 var sort: String?

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad(

  SORTBYCELL.detailTextLabel?.text = sort


} 
  func passdata(sort: String?){
    self.sort = (sort)
  }
```

TableViewController Two:

```
protocol SortProtocol {
func passdata(sort: String?)
 }
 class SortByTable: UITableViewController {

var delegate: SortProtocol?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.delegate = self
}

 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView,         didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let current = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)! as UITableViewCell

    let sort = current.textLabel!.text!

    self.delegate?.passdata(sort)
```

Comment: In vc2, you need to get a reference to vc1 and assign it to the delegate. Are you using a navigation controller?

Comment: put  this 'SORTBYCELL.detailTextLabel?.text = sort "' in func passdata(sort: String?){ ...}   . Because viewDidLoad executes only once when view is loaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to assign the delegate. If you have a "back" button, I'm going to then assume you're using a navigation controller. Using that, we get a reference to the first viewController. Thus, your `viewDidLoad()` in SortByTable will look like:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let searchVC = self.navigationController?.viewControllers[0] as! SearchTableViewController
    self.delegate = searchVC

    tableView.delegate = self
}
```

Comment: any idea on how i keep the checkmark for when the user goes back into the "SortByTable" ? appreciate your help that fixed my problem

Comment: @JoeDodge The checkmark for the previously-selected row? You would need a variable that keeps track of which cell was selected, then when that viewController is back on the screen, you check the variable and set that row to selected

Comment: Yea thats it, awesome ill check it out... started writing iOS apps about a month ago coming from doing web development. i appreciate your help

Comment: @JoeDodge Sure thing. Yw

Comment: got another problem lol... whenever i navigate away from the first tableview and come back and try to pass the data back from tableview two it quits working

Comment: @JoeDodge It's definitely not the most efficient way to do this. Getting a reference to the view controller without a segue is difficult as you can not be sure that SearchTableViewController will always be at the top of the navigation stack. It's why paulvs suggested updating a data model instead. Or you may need to define a global variable, but beware of accidentally changing it somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not mention if you checked that `delegate` is not `nil` (by setting a breakpoint on it for example).

The best option when updating `UITableViewCell`s is to do so via the data source method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

So, in your case, make `passdata` update you data source with the new value of `sort`, then call `tableView.reloadData()` to reload the cell.

Comment: The cells label i am updating is static i just have outlets to each cells label in the file, while the cells that i am choosing from are from an array. i had it working with prepare for segue but i prefer doing it this way. when i click on a cell it prints the correct label it just won't pass it

Comment: I think using the data source is the way to go, I'm not sure if setting `IBOutlet`s from a class to a prototype cell should work.